# Use the_date with link

Tags: date, date-time

How I use the_date with link, a link to archive same date.

```
<?php the_date('l j F Y', '', ''); ?>
```

> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY,
>   the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the
>   first instance of the_date()).

[Function Reference/the date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)

[image: the_date]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: This function shows date only once without a link. I want to show this with a link to the same date that displays.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

Comment: A link to what? A date archive?

Comment: Yes, a link to archive of the same date displayed!

Comment: I think you want [`get_day_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_day_link).

Comment: Look image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9n0uH.jpg